# how can I get a list with calculation in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of coordinates like [[5, 0], [6, 8], [0, 30]]
and I want to create a list of the distance between these coordinates with the relevance like [0, 0]

how can I get the the list [5, 10, 30] in a simple way? (euclidean distance)

Comment: is that _6^2+8^2=10^2_ triangel rule?

Comment: yes it's euclidean distance

Answer (score 3):

Best, if the desired reference point is indeed [0, 0]:

```
>>> input_list = [[5, 0], [6, 8], [0, 30]]
>>> import math
>>> desired_list = [math.hypot(*x) for x in input_list]
>>> print(desired_list)
```

For a more generic point, it's a tad more work:

```
>>> c = [1, 1]
>>> other_list = [math.hypot(x[0]-c[0],x[1]-c[1]) for x in input_list]
>>> print(other_list)
[4.123105625617661, 8.602325267042627, 29.017236257093817]
```

...but not too bad:-).

The core point: **don't** "reinvent Pythagoras' wheel" by doing your own squaring and square roots: `math.hypot` does that on your behalf in a more optimized, more readable way.  You give it the "catheti" (the two shorter sides of a right triangle), it gives you back the hypothenuse (the longest side of that same right triangle).

Added: why can `math.hypot` be faster, I'm asked?  Easy!  Because it does the squaring, addition, and square-rooting "inside", in its C-coded internals, with only one "translation" from the input `PyObject*` to C `double`s, and only one back to the `PyObject*` result.  When coding everything out in Python, several such "translations" are being performed.

Comment: yea i checked it with timeit, math.hypot is more optimized and fast, can you light more on this how its more fast and optimized

Answer (score 1):

Using map function would be good idea.

```
def distance(coord):
    return ((coord[0]**2) + (coord[-1]**2))**0.5
a = [[5,0],[6,8],[0,30]]
b = map(distance,a)  #b = [5.0,10.0,30.0]
```

You could edit distance function according to your reference point.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple list comprehension:

```
from math import sqrt
list = [[5,0],[6,8],[0,30]]
list2 = [sqrt(k[0]**2 + k[1]**2) for k in list]
print(list2)
```

In case you want the distances from a point that isn't (0,0), just change the formula in the definition of list2.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
import math
>>> def distance(my_list,cor):
...     return [math.sqrt(abs(x[0]-cor[0])**2 + abs(x[1]+cor[1])**2) for x in my_list]
... 
>>> distance([[5, 0], [6, 8], [0, 30]],[0,0])
[5.0, 10.0, 30.0]
```

Comment: Not worth taking the `abs` -- sheer overhead, since squaring will work identically on any number `n` as it will on `abs(n)`!-)